# Given distances from a point to three vertices of a rectangle, find the distance to the fourth vertex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rectangles

> **Problem:** $ABCD$ is a rectangle. A point $P$ is $11$ from $A$, $13$ from $B$ and $7$ from $C$. What is the length of $DP=x?$ (Note: $P$ can be inside the rectangle or outside of it.)
>
> [image]

I drew this scenario as best as I could, but I only have triangles with two sides and no angles. How do I begin? Any weird and relatively unknown theorems I should use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: draw lines through $P$ parallel to the sides of rectangle. Use Pythagoras theorem for the lines $PA, PB, PC, PD$ to make up the system of four equations. Then you get the answer $1$.

Details:

[image]

$$\begin{cases} a^2+d^2=x^2 \\ a^2+b^2=11^2 \\ b^2+c^2=13^2 \\ c^2+d^2=7^2\end{cases} \stackrel{(4)-(3)+(2)}{\Rightarrow} x^2=7^2-13^2+11^2=1 \Rightarrow x=1.$$

Comment: I can't see how this helps me. If I draw a vertical line through $P$, parallel to $AD$ and $BC$, I just get right angle triangles knowing only one side.

Comment: Right. Denote the sides of the right angle triangles (four of them) and use the Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Which sides? The sides aligned with the sides of the rectangle or the sides that intersect $P$?

Comment: Please, see my update (complete solution)

Comment: Thank you very much buddy!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Just $x^2+13^2=7^2+11^2$ by Pythagoras theorem.

Let $PK$, $PL$, $PM$ and $PN$ be altitudes of $\Delta DPA$, $\Delta DPC$, $\Delta CPB$ and $\Delta APB$ respectively.
Thus,
$$x^2+13^2=DK^2+KP^2+PM^2+MB^2=PN^2+KP^2+PM^2+PL^2=11^2+7^2$$

Comment: How? $x$ and $13$ are not sides in the same right triangle and $7^2 + 11^2$ is not that triangles hypotenuse.

Comment: Yes, I get it now, thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Parseval You are welcome!

Comment: This is the British flag theorem, which says  "...if a point P is chosen inside a rectangle ABCD, then the sum of the squares of the Euclidean distances from P to two opposite corners of the rectangle equals the sum to the other two opposite corners."