# Finding distance of a vertices of a rectangle from another point in it when distances to other three vertices is given.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, rectangles

Let $X$ be a point inside a rectangle $ABCD$. If $XA=a$, $XB=b$, $XC=c$. Find $XD$.

I tried by using cosine rule on all the triangle formed and equating what I got. Then I tried to find the relations of sines of interior angles that I know will sum up to $360°$ by adding opposite triangles areas and equating them. I tried to then use the $sin(a+b)$ by using all the sines and cosine relations and trying to get them equate to $sin(360°)$ that is zero. But I ended up with a mess and I am stuck.

A solution without trignometry if possible would be better. Hints are always appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* Pythagoras' Theorem. *Spoiler Alert:* duplicate of [Given distances from a point to three vertices of a rectangle, find the distance to the fourth vertex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2393130) (Please check the question hasn't already been answered before posting!)

Comment: Ok Thanks lemme try

Comment: is there no other data about where the point is inside the rectangle ?

Comment: No just distances from 3 pts is given. Btw why downvote?

Comment: @sammygerbil I did it it was quite easy I was just complicating it. Should I check the spoiler now and delete the post now

Comment: $XD=a^2+c^2-b^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
By Pythagoras Theorem, 
$XD^2=XF^2+XH^2$... (1) 
$a^2=XH^2+XE^2$... (2) 
$b^2=XE^2+XG^2$... (3) 
$c^2=XG^2+XF^2$... (4)

(2)+(4)-(3) gives, 
$XF^2+XG^2=c^2+b^2-a^2$
By (1), 
$XD^2=c^2+a^2-b^2$